# Legally speaking, would shooting fire out of your hands, count as a Firearm?

Tags: internal-consistency, super-powers, law

So let's say there's someone who can shoot fire out of their hands. It's understandable that some people would be nervous. My main question is would this man's literal firepower count as a weapon, and thus be subject to laws pertaining to firearms? If no would there be precedent to alter laws to fold this man's ability into firearm legislation.

Comment: Under current law, no, because no one can shoot fire out of their hands. I suspect, however, that in a world that does have people who shoot fire out of their hands, the be-fired would have some legal recourse after being singed, or at least their next of kin would.

Comment: Remember to state what country you mean this for (as a minimum).  Laws are different from place to place.

Comment: And you jump from "weapon" to "firearm". There are reasons for having different words.

Comment: There are [hunting rifles](https://www.airgundepot.com/airforce-texan-air-rifle-scope-combo.html) that aren't subject to laws pertaining to firearms, depending on jurisdiction.

Comment: First of the person would be in a lab, so no laws are necessary.

Comment: We have hundreds of law systems with thousands of precedents and interpretations in each. It would be a really broad task to answer this question fully. What country / state you are thinking about?

Comment: Lolx !  "can shoot ***fire*** out of their ***hands***" ... "laws pertaining to ***firearms***" :-)

Comment: You might want to compare [What could cause normal people to hate magicians?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/97096/29) (Full disclosure: the accepted answer is my own.) While the question is obviously different, some of the reasoning in the answers given may apply to interpretations of existing legal texts as well.

Comment: "I  AM the law."   Problem solved

Comment: Why not ask Law.SE?

Comment: @chrylis Well, a weapon is something that you hold in your hand, and a firearm is when fire shoots out of your arm. At least in this case...

Comment: @AndyD273 I'd assume that a firearm is an arm made of literal fire...

Comment: In our mundane world, you could in theory harm someone by spitting on them while infected with something.  That would not be considered a firearm - but there are still other laws that apply.

Comment: Why would you need a precedent for altering laws?  It would make more sense for precedent to prevent altering laws to make an inherent ability illegal to ... what exactly?  Go within a thousand feet of a school?  Walk around at all?  Attack someone?  Rob a liquor store?  Sell his arms?

Comment: weapon - a thing designed or used for inflicting bodily harm or physical damage, if you use fire to cause harm it is by definition a weapon

Comment: I think even in today's legal definition https://definitions.uslegal.com/w/weapon/ , the term can be generalized to anything that can be used to defeat, injure or destroy. So, sure, superpowers could be used as a weapon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After making several comments against answers here I need to formulate a complete answer from my perspective to this (actually important) question. I'll state at the outset that this answer is based on the Common Law practices of Australia and similar Commonwealth countries. Let's start with the short answer;

**No**

It doesn't matter what superpower you have; you haven't used a 'weapon' on someone else when fighting them. There's a very simple reason for this; weapons are effectively tools. They are something that you pick up and brandish, aim, or throw at your opponent, and they have to (by definition) be separate from the body.

This is a far more important point than you might realise; the minute that we call a fist a 'weapon' you're effectively curtailing the right of that person to defend themselves. Ever. What's worse, you're on a slippery slope.

Has a trained psychologist who utters a hurtful rebuke at someone who then goes and commits suicide committed assault with a deadly weapon? They've used their mind to attack another; surely that counts if a fist does.

In the heat of a home invasion, the owner of the property bites the invader. BUT, the homeowner is HIV positive. Is that person's teeth / blood / saliva a deadly weapon?

At what point do body parts cease being weapons and the person themselves become weapons? Trained special forces soldiers have skills that equate to superpowers by comparison to the average person on the street; does that mean you have the right to tease or taunt them mercilessly until they retaliate simply because you know that they're not 'allowed' to respond?

Of course not. Besides; with deadly weapon assaults, the person can be restricted from owning those kinds of weapons in the future. Even computers fit that category. But hands? Are we really talking about amputating the hands of skilled combatants that make a mistake? For mine, that's a bridge too far.

That said, what DOES fit is *aggravated assault*. The reason why weaponed assault is a separate class of crime is that there is a known amount of damage that one person can usually do to another without tools or weapons. Generally speaking, that means you have a level playing field. While I personally abhor violence in any form and have zero tolerance for it, the law recognises that weapons make any conflict uneven.

Where weapons are NOT used and the conflict is *still* uneven, we have aggravation. What this essentially means is that people with higher levels of combat skill have an obligation to curtail their aggression and attacks on others because of the fact that they are far more effective fighters. This means that they commit aggravated assault, not simple assault if they hurt someone seriously.

I want to state at this point that I'm not saying that the superperson is not *liable* for the damage they cause, and the punishment should still fit the crime, and in all probability the laws around aggravated assault will allow for penalties that match (or more) those for assault with a deadly weapon 30 minutes after the superperson commits this crime.

BUT;

Soldiers receive strong disciplinary training as part of receiving this skill; the superperson may not. Arguably, this is one of those complicated situations where a person with (say) diminished capacity may be guilty of an offence that is both mitigated and aggravated. It's a complex argument in which the danger to the public has to be taken into account as much as the mental and physical capacity of the person involved.

To give an example; in Australia, intoxication has often been seen as a mitigating circumstance in assault. In other words, someone who takes a swing at you when they're drunk is seen to have diminished capacity of their behaviour and therefore less responsible for their actions.

Over the last decade or so however, there has been an increasing prevalence of what is now known as one punch attacks, or the 'Coward's Punch' being perpetrated on random people on the street by heavily intoxicated people. The victims have died, been made quadriplegics or paraplegics, or suffered other serious or permanent disabilities. As a consequence, most states have changed the laws to make intoxication an aggravating factor, not a mitigating factor. The argument is that just like the soldier carries with him an obligation to control his behaviour, the drunkard carries an obligation to limit his anti-social behaviour by removing himself from public places while intoxicated, especially if he's a 'mean' drunk and knows a trick or two in attacking others.

This (respectfully) is only different in relation to scale. Your superperson can burn and disfigure people horribly, and may not possess the self control necessary to constrain him or her self when agitated. This is not only an aggravating factor, it's a serious one and needs to be considered accordingly.

Good law acts as a deterrent to the populace AND an example to others. It does so in a context of fair and objective assessment. In this case, the outcome of any attack by the superperson will be serious, and the superperson needs commensurate control to balance that out. If the only way that can be achieved is to have very serious penalties in place that make the superperson think twice about any attack, then so be it.

But, this is **not** the same as wielding a weapon as that is **always** a choice. This superperson simply cannot put down her 'weapon', even if she wanted to. For that reason alone, I'd be deeply concerned if his or her powers were categorised as a weapon. It's a slippery slope which leads to everyone's unique strength (super or not) being a reason for that person to be controlled in some manner and if that's not a definition for an authoritarian regime, I don't know what is.

Comment: Guam also has a law (§ 62106) that says "Any registered karate or judo expert who thereafter is charged with having used his art in a physical assault on some other person, shall upon conviction thereof, be deemed guilty of aggravated assault."

Comment: " Are we really talking about amputating the hands of skilled combatants that make a mistake? " there's a plot there.

Comment: `[...] there is a known amount of damage that one person can [...] do [barehanded]. Generally speaking, that means you have a level playing field. [...] weapons make any conflict uneven.` --No, different body sizes/builds make nearly all physical confrontations inherently uneven. Weapons level the field by bringing everyone up to the same level of potential damage output. But I'll admit, different places have different laws about it.

Answer (score 20):

The real answer is that the laws will adapt to do what they need to do.

There are some interesting questions about this regarding whether fists of a skilled fighter are considered to be deadly weapons.  [This article](https://combatsportslaw.com/2015/11/03/mixed-martial-artists-hands-deemed-deadly-weapons-in-texas-assault-case/) cites two sides of the issue.  Jamuel Parks was charged with aggravated assault, under the argument that as a MMA fighter, his fists were deadly weapons.  However, that case was difficult to draw a precedent from this because he plead guilty.  It is not clear whether a jury would have found his fists to be deadly weapons in an actual court.  The same article also cites  Ray v. State, a case where the court had decided that hands/feet were not deadly weapons, even if they were used to kill someone.

The [US code](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/921) does make it clear that such a fire skill would not qualify as a firearm.  Firearms are defined to be devices, and an innate skill like that would almost certainly not be considered to be a device.

Comment: I can't speak for the US, but I can't see any possibility in Australia at least for hands to be considered as weapons because weapons are tools, and therefore distinct (removable) from the body. Also, in Australia (and I believe NZ, Canada and UK) the concept of Aggravation (special consideration of the crime as more serious) would apply in this instance. A soldier who attacks someone in AU is probably committing aggravated assault because he's expected to have better control of his superior skills in hand to hand combat. Hands as weapons are a slippery slope IMHO to people as weapons.

Comment: @TimBII, technically speaking, hands can be removed from the body...

Comment: Not in the legal sense meant here.

Comment: I can't remember the exact details, but there is a similar case to "Ray vs State", where someone injured another person by stamping on them.  This *was* classified as "assault with a deadly weapon", but the "weapon" in question was...  A flip-flop the defendant was wearing when they stomped on the victim.  **Not** their foot.  A comparison could be:  does spitting in someone's face count as attacking them with a weapon?

Comment: "The real answer is that the laws will adapt to do what they need to do." More like what some politicians *want* them to do, even if it's a terrible idea.

Comment: I can't speak for other European and/or Civil Law countries, but in France, martial arts training is considered a weapon. There have been people condemned for having defended themselves against unarmed aggression using those. Then again, judges in France have a large power of interpretation (and don't always bother with what the law says, actually), and some of them hate the idea of individuals defending themselves - but that's a dysfunction of the system, not a legal point. However, based on this, superpowers would be considered weapons, and potentially violate measured response.

Comment: Upvote just because of the first sentence. The rest of your answer is certainly interesting but the first sentence is an answer all by itself. Kudos.

Comment: I may be wrong, (and even if I'm not, courts may rule otherwise, the law being what it is) but I was under the impression that the "with a deadly weapon" part was added to highlight that this person had gone to the encounter armed with a weapon designed to cause injury and death, which makes it harder to claim that it wasn't premeditated. Taking a knife/gun/whatever to meet someone is a conscious choice that might indicate intent; regardless of how skilled you are, taking your hands and feet with you is (for most people) not optional.

Comment: This was a number of years ago, but it was my understanding that (in the UK) being a Black Belt or higher in a martial art meant any Bodily Harm Charges could instantly be raised to Grievous Bodily Harm, a much more serious offense. Could have just been an old wives tale, however.

Answer (score 2):

Probably yes, and as such subject to some sort of legislation.

I remember reading of some cases, in our real world, were people expert in martial arts where charged for improper usage of their hands, which in those cases were considered equivalent to weapons.

It's easy to imagine that a superhero, being way more powerful than a Bruce Lee or a Mike Tyson, would be also considered more dangerous in case of inappropriate usage of his/her skills, and therefore subject at least to registration.

Answer (score 2):

*Scottish law answer, as context for the kinds of issues that arise when defining an innate ability as a weapon. Note that Scots Law is a hybrid of Common Law and Civil Law - as such, is a good basis for discussion, as the system has many similarities to the [majority of countries (either entirely common or civil law based)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_law#/media/File:Map_of_the_Legal_systems_of_the_world_(en).png).*

## No, and they Never will

#### Definition of an offensive weapon

In Scottish Law, an **offensive weapon** is defined as:

> any article -
>   (a) made or adapted for use for causing injury to a person, or
>   (b) intended, by the person having the article, for use for causing injury to a person by—
>   . . . .(i) the person having it, or
>   . . . .(ii) some other person,

*[Criminal Law (Consolidation) (Scotland) Act 1995, part VI, section 47](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1995/39/part/VI/crossheading/offensive-weapons)*

As such a weapon must firstly, be an article (an item or object) that can be made or adapted, and must be ownable. That is, parts of a human that can do damage, such as teeth, fists or legs, do not count as offensive weapons.

It should be noted at this point however, that *Iron-man* type abilities, or those involving implants may be considered offensive weapons. As such, the remainder of this answer assumes superpowers to be *X-men* style abilities that do not fit the definition above.

Note also, one of the penalties for carrying an *offensive weapon* is:

> Where any person is convicted of an offence under subsection (1) above the court may make an order for the forfeiture or disposal of any weapon in respect of which the offence was committed.

Clearly, the disposal of a human that weild superpowers does not directly fit into this - as it would conflict with existing human rights laws. As such, superpowers cannot legally be *offensive weapons**.

#### Dangerous Dogs Act

The above is not to say that superpowers could not be made illegal though. A good use-case for how dangerous living things can be classified, is the [Dangerous Dogs Act 1991](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1991/65/introduction):

> An Act to prohibit persons from having in their possession or custody dogs belonging to types bred for fighting; to impose restrictions in respect of such dogs pending the coming into force of the prohibition; to enable restrictions to be imposed in relation to other types of dog which present a serious danger to the public; to make further provision for securing that dogs are kept under proper control; and for connected purposes.

This legislation provides restrictions on ownership of certain breeds of dogs, based on them being a danger to the public. Importantly, at no point are the dogs classified as *weapons* in this legislation - instead, that are covered separately with their own laws and regulations.

This means that owning a dangerous dog can have different penalties, and the control of these dogs can be applied differently to the control of offensive weapons.

For the case of superpowers, this is likely what would happen. A separate legislation would be enacted to cover the use of dangerous innate powers and the people who can weild them. It's an important distinction, as classification as a *weapon* would impose existing restrictions (such as confiscation/destruction) that would arguably not be enforcable to a human (due to other existing laws).

#### Summary

As shown above, the law on what consitutes a weapon is covered by existing legislation. This is likely applicable to most countries, where there will be specific punishments and regulations based on the idea of a weapon being a weildable device - and not an innate ability of a human.

To cover super-powers in the same legislation would be an extremely difficult legal minefield - having to avoid conflicts with any other laws that govern human rights. As such, it is extremely unlikely that a superpower will ever be classified as *a weapon*.

That said, it is not unlikely that they would be controlled separately. As shown with the Dangerous Dogs Act; legislation can be created to deal with a specific issue like this, with its own terms, regulations and penalties. This means that dangerous use of superpowers, would likely be called exactly that - and not shoe-horned into an existing terminology.

So, **while super powers will likely never be classified as a weapon, they will likely be controlled via separate legislation**.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "yes, for sure", and I will use an example for that:
Although it might depend on the legislation of every country, in general internationally, if you are a licensed martial artist (other cases might also be accepted, although it should be proved that you practice some sport combat or martial art), and if you harm someone, you can easily be charged, due to martial arts are considered an aggravation, and it is my understanding that this has a logic behind, mainly 2 reasons:

1. you know how to fight, so, you can use your body and mind in a lethal way in a fight, at least, after a certain level (grade or belt, for example).
2. more important, if you practice martial arts, you are supposed to be able to control a violent situation, in the way that you should be able to block or knock your opponent without harming him seriously, unless that opponent is another martial artist/trained fighter, of course.
   These 2 cases are limited to the case that you don't have any mental problem, but in that case probably you would be in some psychiatric hospital.

So, having superpowers should not very different. If you are not crazy and harm someone, you might have a legal problem. And if you are crazy, not much better ;)

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! I'm not sure how well this answers the question, because you haven't addressed the primary issue of whether those superpowers would count as a *weapon*.

Comment: There is a significant difference between this situation and the question, namely that OP doesn't indicate that the fire-arms require any degree of training, skill or discipline to use. Mastering a lethal martial art requires extensive and *intentional* training to achieve exactly that goal, so holding a trained martial artist responsible for that is a far cry from punishing someone for something that they can just *do* whether they trained at all or even wanted it in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

No.

There is no gun/weapon involved thus is legally an unarmed attack but you can bet your bottom dollar new laws would be drafted the next day.

Answer (score -1):

> My main question is would this man's literal firepower count as a weapon, and thus be subject to laws pertaining to firearms?

Almost anywhere on the planet, using such an ability to harm, threaten or intimidate anyone would be a criminal offense.

Firearms laws vary from place to place, but it would be use of a deadly weapon for sure.

In principle if they behaved themselves they'd be free to go about their business, just as I am as long as I don't beat up anyone with my hand.

However ...

> Reality-Check

This person would be helping government scientists with their questions.

Locked up somewhere (maybe nice, maybe not so nice).  Almost certainly kept incommunicado and considered top secret.

The law would not be an issue and they would never see the light of day ( unless they were given fireproof and heat resistant windows for their prison :-) ).  And it would be lucky for them if it was a government that got to them first, because they'd be in serious trouble if criminals or terrorists did.

Comment: Stephen, I'm not convinced that your statement that it would be use of a deadly weapon is accurate. Assault, absolutely. Even Aggravated Assault (assault that is taken more seriously because of aggravating circumstances), but not use of a deadly weapon. Recently in Australia being intoxicated has been shifted from a mitigating factor to an aggravating factor in assaults for cultural reasons, and trained soldiers and the like can almost ONLY commit aggravated assault because of their responsibility to constrain their skills; this would seem to be in line with that kind of escalation model.

Comment: @TimBII Essentially you're using a flamethrower or a blowtorch or setting fire to them.  Burns are considered very serious from a medical standpoint - they can kill in a lot of ways after the immediate injury and carry high risk of permanent impairment and disfigurement even after "recovery".  The precise definition of these legal terms is going to vary from place to place, but blasting someone with fire is very likely to be interpreted as an assault with a deadly weapon, however it translates into a particular locations criminal law.

Comment: But you're NOT using a flamethrower or blowtorch, are you? You can take a flamethrower off someone, but this is an inherent skill. Sure, laws will change and I'm not arguing the seriousness of the outcome, but this is no different to any uneven contest; aggravation may apply but it's not a weapon under the law because the person can't surrender the 'skill' like it was a tool.

Comment: @TimBII I think you're trying to do something that's impossible : assign a particular criminal interpretation to something which doesn't exist and is far outside of what the law as it exists anywhere now is designed for.  Is it a weapon is rather a minor point as the issues would be the intent of the act, the consequences and whether they the accused persons actions could reasonably have been expected to cause harm.  Whether their hands are weapons or not in some legal or regulatory sense is going to be largely irrelevant.

Comment: You're right; I AM trying to apply an interpretation of the law to something that doesn't exist and which the law doesn't account for. The thing is, in such a case, so would the lawyers be doing that. While I respect your view and fully agree that the outcome of this attack would be horrific, I'm just trying to say that my interpretation avoids the problem of people being punished for their abilities more than their choices, which is what a court is REALLY supposed to decide.

Comment: @TimBII I don't think we're really disagreeing here.  It's a *choice* to hurt deliberately hurt someone unless you're legally considered insane and incapable of making such a decision at the time of the offense.  If I beat you close to death with my hands, that's not going to be interpreted as an *ability*, and neither is setting fire to someone with a unique personal capability.  Either way it was a deliberate act to cause severe harm or even kill.  That's what the courts will end up making a guilty/not-guilty verdict on.

Comment: Agreed Stephen. I think we're discussing the periphery more than the critical issues. Still, as always, enjoyable debate. :)